# Fulfillment SYNC action.devices.types.GARAGE device only show settings page

Tags: google-smart-home

I'm trying implementing a action.devices.types.GARAGE device but when I get the SYNC the garage device show up with an gear icon and when I press it it only show the device settings.
I implement another devices with action.devices.types.LIGHT, action.devices.types.SWITCH and action.devices.types.OUTLET and all works fine.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

[image: Google Home Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The device type `GARAGE` does not have touch control support, while`OUTLET`, `SWITCH`, and `LIGHT` do. You can see the full list of devices with touch control support in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/touch-controls#supported_device_types).

If you can still use voice control to control the `GARAGE` through your integration, then everything is working as expected.